# Show custom message

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to return a message to the SQL client when a certain condition in an after trigger is met. I used the RAISERROR function but the error message contains more information than my custom message (like the query used in the trigger). What did I miss?

Comment: Show us the code and we will show you the solution :)

Comment: Did you think about the approach to use the application/service layer instead of database layer for error messages? You can simply manage exceptions on, for example, .net program. If you can use only SQL Server, you can TRY/CATCH the exception and return the ERROR_MESSAGE (or your own message) to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your message in custom format before raise. For example:

```
Declare @Message NVARCHAR(1000)=''
Select Top 10 @Message = @Message +','+Name
From YourTable
Where Condition

Set @Message = 'List OF Names In Your Table: ' + @Message

RAISERROR (@Message,16,1)
```